# splist results into groups

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I've got a basic query to return splist items but I would like to further categorize them to display them in groups(Corporate, ICT, Performance). The Group values are stored in column named TeamDivison on the same list. Im trying to make this efficient as possible.
Thanks

```
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
 string filter = "Team";

            query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Template'/><Value Type='String'>" + filter + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

            SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

            foreach (SPListItem item in items) 
            {
                if (items != null)
                {
                // Check team division column, put into appropriate group(Corporate, ICT, Performance). 
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SPGridView, you can achieve the grouping by the below code

```
spgridview.AllowGrouping = true;
spgridview.AllowGroupCollapse = true;
spgridview.GroupField = "TeamDivison";
spgridview.GroupDescriptionField = "TeamDivison";
spgridview.GroupFieldDisplayName = "TeamDivison";
```

else, This article might be useful for you,
http://tarunaverma.wordpress.com/2012/03/18/caml-query-for-group-by-count-and-data/